# How to load database content to textarea when it contains embedded video using CKEditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

I have troubles saving the embedding code for videos using CKEditor.
Basically, either using the plugin or using the embed code directly from youtube, my code works perfectly fine when saving to the database. When the public page loads, the video is embedded correctly.

Yet, when I reload the data for editing, the movie is not showing in the textarea, even though the code is there, as shown below:

```
    <textarea id="content_22" name="content_22" class="ckta" >
<div class=\"raw-html-embed\"><iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/Drzrlkjerlzj\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen=\"\">
</iframe>
</div>
</textarea>
```

I guess it is a matter of escaping characters.

My current strategy is the following, but I never know what I am overdoing or not:

```
        $content = trim(stripslashes($data['paragraph']));
        $content = str_replace(CHR(10), "", $content);
        $content = str_replace(CHR(13), "", $content);
        $content = addslashes($content);
```

**Edit:**

I actually managed to display the video embedding by removing the last line :

```
//$content = addslashes($content);
```

Yet, now the display of the video only works when I use Raw html embedding within CKEditor, together with the embedding code provided by Youtube. It does not work when simply copying and pasting the URL in the textarea using the Media plugin.

I think it is due to the "oembed" code generated

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put HTML elements inside a textarea.

Try to use [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) instead.

Comment: well, this is CKEditor taking care of this. I actually removed the last "addslashes", and now, the editing mode works fine. Yet, the display mode only works with Youtube embedding code and not with the "oembed" code generated by CKEditor using the media plugin.